# condition to load only some script and not all in the index.html using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will briefly comment on my problem. I have a giant development, and I've noticed that it does not work for internet explorer. then if the user enters from internet explorer the files that produce error will not be loaded, only the files that are compatible and do not generate error will be loaded.
This is my logic, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I'm not interested if I can do it directly from pure javascript. Thank you very much.

```
    <script src='app/constantes.js'></script>
    <script src='app/controllers.js'></script>
    if(!internet explorer)
        <script src='app/app.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/landing/landingController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/reportes/reportesController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/reportes/reportesReceptorController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/contacto/contactoController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/acerca/acercaController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/loginController.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/page404/page404Controller.js'></script>
    else 
        <script src='app/app_internetexplorer.js'></script>
        <script src='components/controllers/incompatible/incompatibleController.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the way I prefer is to create `script` tag and inject it dynamically in `DOM` based on your condition, following is what am pointing at :-

use `window.navigator.userAgent` to decide on `browser` (internet explorer in your case) and initialize it in `internet_explorer`

you can use `array` to keep all your `js` files in one place and `loop` through it, like

```
var other_browser_scripts = ['app/app.js',
    'components/controllers/landing/landingController.js',
    'components/controllers/reportes/reportesController.js',
    'components/controllers/reportes/reportesReceptorController.js',
    'components/controllers/contacto/contactoController.js',
    'components/controllers/acerca/acercaController.js',
    'components/controllers/loginController.js',
    'components/controllers/page404/page404Controller.js'],

internet_explorer_scripts = ['app/app_internetexplorer.js',
   'components/controllers/incompatible/incompatibleController.js'];


var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";

if(!internet_explorer)
{
   for(var i = 0; i < other_browser_scripts.length; i++) {
       js.src = other_browser_scripts[j];
       dumpToDOM();
   }
}
else
{
   for(var j = 0; j < internet_explorer_scripts; j++) {
   js.src = internet_explorer_scripts[j];
   dumpToDOM();
}

function dumpToDOM(){
   head.appendChild(js);
   js = document.createElement("script");
   js.type = "text/javascript";
}
```

Comment: but how do I load the others? can you be a little more detailed please? for example for load the two script in the case of  using internet explorer (look my example)

Comment: edited to suit your need, just use an `array` and loop through it :)